# Angular2 Routes, Components and Inputs: Can they work together?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component that has a set of inputs in takes in. This component is generic and basically takes in a bunch inputs to config it a certain way. I've recently had a requirement that this component needs to be used as part of a RouteConfig. The issue I am running into is that I don't see how you can supply these inputs through the RouteConfig like you could through bindings or component references.

The only solution I can forsee if to create a level between this component and the route which creates these inputs and then loads the component but is there a way around not having to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: In case of route data, you can use `RouteParams` to extract data.

Answer (score 1):

For how to get `RouteParams` see [How to get GET paramater in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784822/how-to-get-get-paramater-in-angular2/36785222)

If your component should work as a routed component **and** as a statically added component that uses `@Input()`s and `@Output()`s for binding, using a wrapper is IMHO the best approach.